# Search results page with parameters passed in url returns status 404

Tags: php, laravel

Attempting to implement a simple search on my laravel website with the use of the following form:

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/search-results" class="cse-search-box"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-mygoogleid:myid"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8"> 
    <input type="text" class="search-inp icon" name="q" size="30" placeholder="Search my site"> 
</form>
```

The url that is generated by this form is:

```
https://www.examlle.com/search-results?cx=partner-pub-mygoogleid%myid&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=searchterm`
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('search-results', 'SearchController@getResults');
```

All seems to work except one very interesting thing, the search-results page shows status 404.

When i remove parameters from the url then the status changes to 200.

Any idea why this is happening or any suggestion how to implement this form so that its response is 200 when parameters are present?

Comment: Maybe, you misspelled your id. If a non existent id comes in, pages usually return 404 as an error code, to let you know that such an id does not exists.

Comment: What is the http status of a get request to https://www.examlle.com/search-results?param=value

Comment: @Kurt, the http status code is 404, but the page is actually displaying correctly in the browser

Comment: @AlexB Well that is even more bizarre. You are likely going to need to do some manual debugging/xdebugging here.  :( Hopefully someone else can solve it for you.

Comment: You get this error, because the route is not defined.    `q?q=example` and `q/?q=example` are different route. Give a slash on form action as : `action="https://www.example.com/search-results/"` and the error will vanish

Comment: @STA, will give it a shot. Will post back here

Comment: @STA, I have tried adding `/` to the `url` in the form action, but the situation with 404 has not changed. As I have mentioned, when I remove all params from the URL then the status 404 changes to status 200

Comment: Could this be down to the NGINX settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my `nginx.conf`

The problem was inside the location php block with this line `try_files $query_string/index.php =404;`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # try_files $query_string/index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

After commenting it out everything works as intended and I no longer have `status 404` on my search results page